# Take the derivative of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

I have to take the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and should use $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$.

So I have $\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{h}$

Then $\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

I got $\displaystyle\frac{1-(x+h)^2-1-x^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

and here after I dont know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You first step is correct, but, what you get is

$\displaystyle\frac{1-(x+h)^2-1+x^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+h\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Then, notice that when $h\rightarrow 0$, then both nominator and denominator goes to 0, so you cannot just take the limit $h=0$ here. Instead, you should make further transformations:

$\displaystyle\frac{1-(x+h)^2-1+x^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+h\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$

$\displaystyle\frac{-2xh-h^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+h\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$

$\displaystyle\frac{-2x-h}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\rightarrow$

(now you can take the limit easily by putting $h=0$ into the expression)

$\displaystyle\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}=$

$\displaystyle\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$

Comment: it is not positive x^2 it is negative x^2 in the numerator

Comment: it is $(1-(x+h)^2)-(1-x^2)=1-(x+h)^2-1+x^2$, so positive, if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The last line will be $$\frac{1-(x+h)^2-(1-x^2)}{h(\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$

$$=-\frac{h(h+2x)}{h(\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2})}$$

Now cancel out $h$ as $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

Finally set $h=0$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1-(x+h)^2-1-x^2}{h(\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2})}=\frac{-2xh-h^2}{h(\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2})}=\frac{-2x-h}{(\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2})}\to \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ as $h\to0$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\frac{1-(x+h)^2-1+x^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}= \frac{1-(x^2+2xh+h^2)-1+x^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
=\frac{-2xh-h^2}{h\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\\
=\frac{-2x-h}{\sqrt{1-(x+h)^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\to\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

as $h\to0$